# Any idea how to resolve this with aws glue python job?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-glue

I am trying to pass on some external python libraries to my job using the job parameters. Here is the parameter I am using

`--additional-python-modules s3://glue/pythonlib/google_api_python_client-2.72.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl`

I keep the getting the following error

`Some pip modules could not be installed. This may mean that you have requested a module that does not exist or produced an error: s3://glue/pythonlib/google_api_python_client-2.72.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl.`

Any idea how to resolve this issue ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For whl files on S3 you need to use the `--extra-py-files` argument.

The `--additional-python-modules` argument is for passing in a comma separated list of dependencies like you would with pip.

As the dependency you are trying to pull into your job is on PyPi, you can simply use:

```
--extra-py-files google-api-python-client==2.72.0
```

But if you want to use the whl from your S3 bucket then use:

```
--additional-python-modules s3://glue/pythonlib/google_api_python_client-2.72.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
```

Details on https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/add-job-python.html